# UICollectionview in a keyboard extension

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios-keyboard-extension, swift-extensions

I have tried to get a UICollectionview into my keyboard extension, which i made in swift. But i can´t get it to work. The keyboard just crashes on launch. Anyone know how to fix this? Or is it even possible to use a UICollectionview in a keyboard extension.

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource{

```
@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var testButton: UIButton!

var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    // Add custom view sizing constraints here
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)


    // Perform custom UI setup here
    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .System)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), forState: .Normal)
    self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

    let nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    let nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
    self.view.addConstraints([nextKeyboardButtonLeftSideConstraint, nextKeyboardButtonBottomConstraint])

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}

override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 14
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    return cell
}

override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
        textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
}
```

}

Comment: How about showing us some code?

Comment: @NRitH Im sorry for not showing any code but i have edited my post with the code that is used to run the keyboard

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add these line in **viewDidAppear** not in **viewDidLoad**

```
let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)

collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView.dataSource = self
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
```

Comment: I want to add custom cell, is it possible?
The cell which is having UIImageView.