# Collection View as Custom Keyboard not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I am building application where you have custom keyboard.

Inside it's class I have created collection view, here is code:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

let stickerImages = [
    UIImage(named: "Image-1"),
    UIImage(named: "Image-2"),
    UIImage(named: "Image-3"),
    UIImage(named: "Image-4"),
    UIImage(named: "Image-5")
]

@IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(StickersCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: StickersCell.reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

    self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), for: [])
    self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
    self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.nextKeyboardButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

    self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

    self.nextKeyboardButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.nextKeyboardButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    self.collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    self.collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    self.collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    self.collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func textWillChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(_ textInput: UITextInput?) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    let proxy = self.textDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.dark {
        textColor = UIColor.white
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, for: [])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return stickerImages.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: StickersCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StickersCell

    cell.setImage(stickerImages[indexPath.item]!)

    return cell
}}
```

And here is my Collection View cell class:

```
class StickersCell: UICollectionViewCell {

static let reuseIdentifier: String = "StickersCell"

lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    contentView.addSubview(imageView)

    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
}}
```

This code works just fine when adding collection view to any `UIView` or `UIViewController`, but when trying to add it to keyboard it throws such errors:

[image: Errors]

As far as I understand I have placed constraints wrong, but I don't understand what exactly is wrong, especially when it's working fine in simple views or view controllers.

I have googled allot and couldn't find any solutions... 
Also this SO questions didn't help as well:

1. [First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40113114/ios-custom-keyboard-with-collection-view-constraints-issue)
2. [Second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329247/uicollectionview-in-a-keyboard-extension)
3. [Third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329247/uicollectionview-in-a-keyboard-extension)

I have also tried moving code that creates collection view into `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` methods but same no luck.

Another strange thing:
If I add simple `UIView` with same constraints to keyboard - everything is working fine. Problem seems to be specifically with collection view.

So, what I have missed? Would be grateful for any help, since I'm battling with this issue for over a week already...

**UPDATE:**

After reading Apple dev forums, idea came up to my mind: 
I have created `UITableView` same as `UICollectionView` before and strangely it works. So there's next question: 
**Are you able to use `UICollectionView` as custom keyboard at all?**

Comment: it tells you make a breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch it in the debugger

Comment: @mohsen I have added breakpoint, but no errors there... maybe I added it wrong? I used this guide - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855001/8945677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After battling with this issue for 2 weeks finally found working workaround:

For some reason you can't use `UIImageView` or `MSStickerView` inside `UICollectionViewCell` same as in iMessage Extension, so instead I just added transparent `UIButton` with `UIImage` inside this button and it worked!

Still don't know why you can't use images or views and couldn't find any specific info about it, but my solutions works and I hope this will help someone in future.